# Error message in Informix

Tags: sql, database, informix

This is the code issued and the error message:.

```
dbuser@test:/var/lib/dbspace/bosarc/Active_Sites/Port_Hope> dbaccess labor32<<?
> INSERT INTO SCH_DAILY (ssn,time_start,week_day,time_end,dept_key,pos_id,sched_time,break_minutes,comments,start_time,end_time,report_date,week_start_date) values (000287752,2016-02-04 16:00:00,5,2016-02-04 12:00:00,D000000007,CASHIE,8.0,0,0,16:00 a,12:00 p,2016-02-04 00:00:00,2016-01-29 00:00:00,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
> ?

Database selected.


  201: A syntax error has occurred.
Error in line 1
Near character position 178


Database closed.

dbuser@test:/var/lib/dbspace/bosarc/Active_Sites/Port_Hope>
```

I even tried downloading the file directly from the database and match it to the info I am trying to load.

Database file

```
555005875|2016-01-21 16:00:00|5|2016-01-21 22:00:00|D000000007|CASHIE|6.0|0||04:00 p |10:00 p|2016-01-21 00:00:00|2016-01-15 00:00:00||||
```

What I'm trying to insert:

```
000287752,2016-02-04 16:00:00,5,2016-02-04 12:00:00,D000000007,CASHIE,8.0,0,0,16:00 a,12:00 p,2016-02-04 00:00:00,2016-01-29 00:00:00,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

Comment: You need single quotes around the strings and date/time literals.

Answer (score 2):

The DATETIME values such as `2016-02-04 16:00:00` must be enclosed in quotes (either `'2016-02-04 16:00:00'` or `"2016-02-04 16:00:00"`), or dressed up more ornately — verbosely — as a DATETIME literal: `DATETIME(2016-02-04 16:00:00) YEAR TO SECOND`.  On the whole, the quotes are simpler.  This is not necessary when the data is in a load-format file and loaded via the LOAD command of DB-Access, or one of the loader utilities.

The AM/PM time values such as `16:00 a` and `12:00 p` are more problematic still — unless they're inserted into a character column.  Informix supports DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE which would accept values 00:00 .. 23:59 as valid times within a day.

`16:00 a` is not normally how you write `4:00 p`; you either use a value in the range `01:00` .. `12:59` with the suffix (remembering that all of the times `12:00 a` .. `12:59 a` occur before `01:00 a`), or you use 24-hour clock `00:00` .. `23:59`.  On the whole, the latter is more sensible.  If they're going to be handled with the AM/PM suffixes, then you have to wrap the value up as a string in an appropriate `TO_DATE` function call that converts the value to DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE.  But the appropriate function is going to reject `16:00 a` as invalid.

Comment: There's also a bare word `CASHIE` in the insert value list (it's horrid having the code scrolling off the right like that), which would have to be enclosed in quotes too.  Generally, there are a lot of quotes missing.

Answer (score 0):

First, has @gordon-linoff said, you have to enclose the strings and datetime/literals with quotes.

Then, probably you will get the next error:

> 236: Number of columns in INSERT does not match number of VALUES.

This is because you put 13 attributes on the `INSERT` and pass 17 `VALUES`, the `NULLS` should be the issue.

Then, probably, you can get:

> 1263: A field in a datetime or interval values is incorrect or an illegal operation specified on datetime field.

If you get this try passing the values of date/time with the `TO_DATE` function:

```
TO_DATE('216-02-02 12:16:24','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
TO_DATE('23:24','%H:%M') -- 24H format
TO_DATE('11:24 PM','%I:%M %p') -- 12H format AM/PM
```

Although I believe that the `start_time` and the `end_ time` aren’t a date type.

In your case try the next `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO SCH_DAILY(  
    ssn,
    time_start,
    week_day,
    time_end,
    dept_key,
    pos_id,
    sched_time,
    break_minutes,
    comme‌​nts,
    start_time,
    end_time,
    report_date,
    week_start_date
) VALUES (
    '000287752',
    '2016-02-04 16:00:00',
    5,
    '2016-02-04 12:00:00',
    'D000000007',
    'CASHIE',
    8.0,
    0,
    0,
    '16:00 a',
    '12:00 p',
    '2016-02-04 00:00:00',
    '2016-01-29 00:00:00'
);
```

Comment: The values for the start and end times are a valid data type.  In standard SQL, they'd be TIMESTAMP; in Informix, they are DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND.

Comment: @jonathan-leffler I was talking about the ones that show has `04:00 p`.

Comment: your right, it bypass where i was getting the error and now i am getting the error it looks like at the next sequence for the date even though i have quotes.

Comment: dbuser@test:/var/lib/dbspace/bosarc/Active_Sites/Port_Hope> dbaccess labor32<<?
> INSERT INTO SCH_DAILY (ssn,time_start,week_day,time_end,dept_key,pos_id,sched_time,break_minutes,comments,start_time,end_time,report_date,week_start_date) values (000287752,'2016-02-04 16:00:00',5,'2016-02-04 12:00:00',D000000007,CASHIE,8.0,0,0,'16:00 a','12:00 p','2016-02-04 00:00:00','2016-01-29 00:00:00',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
Near character position 220

Comment: @user5161585 your string literals must have quotes also, and drop the NULL, The error for my understanding should be on the dept_key. Check my edit answer I will post there an INSERT that should work.